# Problems adding custom meta description to WordPress after latest update

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've been working on a plug-in that will allow the user to input a meta tag description to go on their page. It was working fine then after the latest WordPress update it is not working. Is there anything in this code that might lead to this new issue?

UPDATE- I've worked out that the wp_head hook is not working on the add_action. I tried deleting everything from the function and calling an echo, but it did not work. I then tried putting echoes in other lines outside of the function and those worked fine.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'oa_set_custom_meta_description');

function oa_set_custom_meta_description() {
    $custom_meta_description = get_option('oa_custom_meta_description', '');

    if (!empty($custom_meta_description)) {
        echo '<meta name="description" content="' . esc_attr($custom_meta_description) . '">';
    }
}

//This is the echo I tried

add_action( 'wp_head', function () {

    echo('TEST');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should be fine. Did you check if `$oa_custom_meta_description`really exists in the Database? And did you try to print the variable with `print_r( $oa_custom_meta_description );`?

However, I am wondering how your system works with `get_option()` wouldn't it make more sense to use `get_post_meta()`?